# Hybrid blending textures

Tags: graphics, colors, xna, textures, xna-4.0

In a game that I am currently developing I use textures with premultiplied alpha colors (the default in XNA 4). On that basis, I create hybrid blending textures, which means that I mix traditional color alphablending and additive blending in one texture.

Basically, this is achieved by creating textures that include pixels of solid (RGBA with A = 255), transparent (R'G'B'A with A < 255 and R' = R * A) and additive blending colors (R''G''B''A with A < 255 and R'' != R * A). Usually, pure additive blending assumes A = 0 but that is not required here. The textures are created in the game by a mathematical function.

Now the problem is that these textures work great in the game but there seems to be no software tool that is able to edit such textures. While the PNG format seems to be able to keep the color information intact, any attempt to edit or save such file destroys the colors. So far I tried Adobe Photoshop, Gimp, Corel Draw and Visual Studio 11.

What I ultimately want to do is load these textures in a software and edit them and possibly save them as DDS (creating mipmaps).